# prove that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective if and only if $f(f^{-1}(C))=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-writing

I need help with proving this:

$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective if and only if $f(f^{-1}(C))=C$

$C\subseteq Y$

Thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to prove one of the implications?

Comment: I started with using definitions of image and preimage and from $f(f^{-1}(C))$ I get $\{y \in Y | \exists x\in X f(x)=y\}\cup \{y\in Y|y\in C\}$. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: @Joey Do you mean "$\;f : X \to Y\;$ is surjective if and only if _for every_ $\;C \subseteq Y\;$, $\;f(f^{-1}(C)) = C\;$"?

Answer (score 1):

Proving that $f(f^{-1}(C)) \subset C$ is trival(not only when $f$ is surjective).

Let us take $y \in C$  and $f$ is onto there is  $x \in f^{-1}(C)$ such that $f(x)=y$ so $y \in f(f^{-1}(C)$ so $C \subset f(f^{-1}(C))$ and $C=f(f^{-1}(C))$.

Comment: Counterexample $f=\log$, $C=\mathbb{R}$, $x=0$.

Comment: But log isnt onto.

Comment: typo: you probably mixed up $x$ and $y$. It should be: ...such that $f\left(y\right)=x$ so $x\in f\left(f^{-1}\left(C\right)\right)$

Comment: The logarithm is a bijective map $\log:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$. As drhab said, the post is wrong as it is written now. My intention was that you should reread the text and find the error by yourself which I am sure you can.

Comment: I have edited your answer. Please check it.

Comment: @AD. I have not notice that the question was if and only if (As you can see i showed that if f is onto then $C=f(f^{-1}(C))$)

Comment: After drhab edit it looks much better.

Comment: I tried to write it fast to be the first one,and mixed up between x and y

Answer (score 0):

Notational convenience: I'm assuming $\;x \in X, y \in Y\;$ throughout this answer.  For clarity, I'm also writing $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$ if a function is not applied to a single element of its domain but to a subset of its domain.

Just expanding the definitions and basic properties, and then simplifying, results in the following calculation: for every $\;C\;$ for which $\;C \subseteq Y\;$,
\begin{align}
& f[f^{-1}[C]] = C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set extensionality, using the fact that each side $\;\subseteq Y\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: y \in f[f^{-1}[C]] \;\equiv\; y \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the basic property of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: \langle \exists x :: x \in f^{-1}[C] \land f(x) = y \rangle \;\equiv\; y \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the basic property of $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: \langle \exists x :: f(x) \in C \land f(x) = y \rangle \;\equiv\; y \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: substitute $\;y = \ldots\;$ on other side of $\;\land\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: \langle \exists x :: y \in C \land f(x) = y \rangle \;\equiv\; y \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: pull $\;y \in C\;$, which does not use $\;x\;$, outside of $\;\exists x\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: y \in C \land \langle \exists x :: f(x) = y \rangle \;\equiv\; y \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: $\;P \land Q \equiv P\;$ is one of the ways to write $\;P \Rightarrow Q\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: y \in C \;\Rightarrow\; \langle \exists x :: f(x) = y \rangle \rangle \\
\end{align}

And we can now complete the proof by adding in $\;\forall C\;$:
\begin{align}
& \langle \forall C :: C \subseteq Y \;\Rightarrow\; f[f^{-1}[C]] = C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the above calculation"} \\
& \langle \forall C :: C \subseteq Y \;\Rightarrow\; \langle \forall y :: y \in C \;\Rightarrow\; \langle \exists x :: f(x) = y \rangle \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set theory: simplify"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: y \in Y \;\Rightarrow\; \langle \exists x :: f(x) = y \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of surjectivity"} \\
& f \text{ is surjective} \\
\end{align}