# Surjection Equivalence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-writing

I'm trying to show that if a function $f:X\to Y$ is surjective it's equivalent to saying that $f \left(f^{-1}(B)\right) = B$ for each  $B \subseteq Y$.

The definition of surjective that I'm using is that $f$ is a surjective function from $X$ to $Y$ with $f(X)=Y$.

Comment: to prove $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$ you've gotta try to prove $f (f^{-1}(B))\supseteq B$ and $f (f^{-1}(B))\subseteq B$

Comment: $f(f^{-1}(B))\subset B$ is obvious, and true of any function. Read: "f takes the things that f takes into B, into B."

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 Now I see the inconsistency that caused your edit from $f[X]$ to $f(X)$, apologies for missing that earlier.  I have deleted my earlier comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete proof, but in a style that you may not be used to.

Putting it formally, you are being asked to prove
$$
\langle \forall B : B \subseteq Y : f[f^{-1}[B]] = B \rangle \;\equiv\; f[X] = Y
$$
For brevity, I'm implicitly assuming $\;x \in X\;$ and $\;y \in Y\;$ in this answer.

Let's first try to simplify $\;f[f^{-1}[B]]\;$, by calculating its elements $\;y\;$, using the basic properties of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$ and $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$ and predicate logic:

\begin{align}
& y \in f[ f^{-1}[B]] \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"basic property of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : x \in f^{-1}[B] \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"basic property of $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : f(x) \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: substitute"} \\
& \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : y \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: extract $\;x\;$-less part out of $\;\exists x\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : \text{true} \rangle \;\land\; y \in B \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$, using implict $\;x \in X\;$"} \\
& y \in f[X] \;\land\; y \in B \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& y \in f[X] \cap B \\
\end{align}

Now we can easily prove the original statement:
\begin{align}
& \langle \forall B : B \subseteq Y : f[f^{-1}[B]] = B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"by the above calculation"} \\
& \langle \forall B : B \subseteq Y : f[X] \cap B = B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"set theory"} \\
& \langle \forall B : B \subseteq Y : B \subseteq f[X] \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"set theory"} \\
& Y \subseteq f[X] \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"use $\;f[X] \subseteq Y\;$ which follows from $\;f : X \to Y\;$"} \\
& f[X] = Y \\
\end{align}

Comment: Right after typing this answer, I discovered this question is a duplicate, where I already answered the original in a similar way; see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/592908/11994.  Going to flag it.